# Referencing an artifact built by Github Actions

Tags: github, build, github-actions

The [upload/download artifact documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#uploading-build-and-test-artifacts) implies that one should be able to build into the `dist` folder. My interpretation of this is that we can then reference this content in, for example, a static site, so that a site auto-builds itself for github pages on master pushes. However, it seems that artifacts are only uploaded to a [specific location](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#list-artifacts-for-a-repository) (i.e. `GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/artifacts` ) and can be downloaded only in zipped format, which defeats the purpose.

Is there a way to populate the `dist` folder of the repo, so that the file that was built becomes publicly and permanently accessible as part of the repo, and I can reference it without having to deploy it elsewhere like S3 etc?

#### Example

Here's a use case:

- I have a dashboard which parses some data from several remote locations and shows it in charts. The page is deployed from `/docs` because it's a Github Pages hosted page.
- the web page only reads static, cached data from `/docs/cache/dump.json`.
- the `dump.json` file is generated via a scheduled Github Action which invokes a script that goes to the data sources and generates the dump.

This is how the web page can function quickly without on-page lockups due to lengthy data processing while the dump generation happes in the background. The web page periodically re-reads the `/docs/cache/dump.json` file to get new data, which should override old data on every scheduled trigger.

The idea is to have the action run and replace the `dump.json` file periodically, but all I can do is produce an artifact which I then have to manually fetch and unzip. Ideally, it would just replace the current `dump.json` file in place.

Answer (score 0):

To persist changes made by a build process, it is necessary to add and commit them like after any change to a repo. Several actions exist for this, like [this one](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/add-commit).

So you would add the following to the workflow:

```yaml
      - name: Commit changes
        uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v7
        with:
          author_name: Commitobot
          author_email: my@mail.com
          message: "Updating build result!"
          add: "docs/cache/dump.json"
```